# How to get data from one file to another file in a Tablewidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyodbc

I am new to python and Im working on a personal project to mannage my workshop i have a QDialog.ui to with a tablewidget that i want to fill with a SQL Server query in a file called DBtest.py, and I have my main Index_test.py file but cant communicate both of the can some one give me a hint?

```
main index_test.py
```

```
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import DBtest
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
import pyodbc

ui,_ = loadUiType('Simple.ui')

class MainApp(QDialog , ui):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self) #sacar en nombre del UI
        self.setupUi(self) #muestra el ui en esta aplicacion

    def Show_Table():
        DBtest.Show_Clientes(data)




def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

DBtest.py

```
class ShowData():

    def Show_Clientes(self):
        self.db = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                                  'Server=PC-ROMO-INGENIE\MTDB;'
                                  'Database=dbsistema;'
                                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute ('''SELECT nombre, RFC, descripcion, direccion, telefono, email FROM cliente Where tipo_cliente = 'Cliente' ''')
        data = self.cursor.fetchall()

        if data :
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(0)
            for row , form in enumerate(data):
                for column , item in enumerate(form):
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row , column , QTableWidgetItem(str(item)))
                    column += 1
                row_position =  self.tableWidget.rowCount()
                self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_position)
```

Comment: I Can make it work in a single file but cant comunicate with 2 py Files

Comment: Thanks @Dennis Jensen do you have  a tag name or server? by the way I just solved it   `class MainApp(QDialog , ui):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self) #sacar en nombre del UI
        self.setupUi(self) #muestra el ui en esta aplicacion
        Show_dbclass = DBtest.Show_Clientes(self)

        
    def Show_Table(self):
        self.Show_dbclass()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`

Comment: Interesting to see that you post the potential for more in depth one-on-one free help and stackoverflow chooses to delete it makes you kind of wonder what the moderators are really thinking and whose best interest they are trying to server ... there own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it, I had to import DBtest.py into the index.py and run the

```
 `from PyQt5.QtCore import *
  from PyQt5.QtGui import *
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
  import sys
  import DBtest #import this py file
  from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
  import pyodbc

   ui,_ = loadUiType('Simple.ui')


  class MainApp(QDialog , ui):
     def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self) 
    self.setupUi(self) 
    Show_dbclass = DBtest.Show_Clientes(self)#here 


   def Show_Table(self):
    self.Show_dbclass()

def main():
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainApp()
window.show()
app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()`
```